# apply css to specific element in array

Tags: php, css, mysql, arrays, foreach

I am fetching data of employees from mysql database into array and displaying in table.
everything is working but i want to apply a condition in array that

If **salary** is greater then 30,000 then change its color to **red** .

**Tried**

```
$q = "select name, salary from array";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $q);
$arr = array();
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $arr[] = $data;
}
echo '<table class="table table-hover">
      <th>Name</th><th>Salary</th>';
$keys = array_keys($arr); 
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value  , ";
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>'; 

    foreach ($arr[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
      if ($arr[$keys[$i]['salary']] > 34000) {
        echo "<td style='color: red; background-color:pink;'> $key=>$value </td>";
      }else{
          echo "<td> $key=>$value </td>";
      }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

**this is how my table looks**

[image]

i want to change color of salary if it is greater than 30,000...

Comment: *"is greater then 30,000"* and you're using `> 34000`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($arr[$keys[$i]['salary']] > 34000) {
```

to

```
if ($value > 30000) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got a little lost when processing an array which contains another arrays. A simple foreach loop is the simplest way of dealing with this.

```
echo '<table class="table table-hover"><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th>';

foreach ($arr as $row) {
    echo '<tr>'; 

    // using a ternary operator here rather than an IF
    $style = $row['salary'] > 30000 
            ? ' style="color:red;background-color:pink;"' 
            : '';

    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td $style>{$row['salary']}</td>";

    echo '</tr>';
}
```